# Materials Panel Missing in Blender

Tags: 3d, tabs, blender

I am trying to add a material, but after selecting the object I want to add the material to (or selecting *anything* for that matter), and I click on the materials tab in the properties view, nothing is listed. The entire window is completely blank.

See the image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Scroll up and you'll find it there (take a look at the scroll bar, it's scrolled down) :)

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that. It seems to be by default scrolled down. Haha

Comment: Gosh, absolutely the same here. :D Thank you, @DJK! (Why haven't you answered this in a proper A?)

Comment: I did same mistake oh my god :)

Answer (score 2):

Scroll up. Occasionally, the material panel is scrolled down by default, hiding all the options, as can be seen on the scroll bar in your image.

Full credit to *DJK* for this; I just put it in answer format.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I changed blender render (drop down at the top of the screen) to Cycles Render and it showed up